# Decoding Ajax Response in WebKit browser is having issue

Tags: ajax, cross-browser, webkit, decoding

Issue: 
We were having issue with one of the ajax request in webkit browsers ( Chrome, Firefox, and Safari).

scenarios working:
1. If we configure chrome/firefox with Fiddler and enable https decryption in fiddler it works as expected. 
2. Works properly in internet explorer.

We were able to see response on page, but if you go to networking tab and check response it's null and request is not complete it's spinning. we were thinking it's more of webkit browser decoding issue.

Please share if you have any idea how to fix or what might be causing this issue, any input will be appreciated.

**Raw HTTP Header**

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-encoding: gzip
content-language: en-US
content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
date: Wed, 19 Aug 2015 18:38:23 GMT
p3p: CP="NON CUR OTPi OUR NOR UNI"
vary: X-Forwarded-Host
transfer-encoding: chunked
server-name: app2
cache-control: private, must-revalidate, max-age: 0
x-powered-by: Servlet/3.0
x-ua-compatible: IE=edge
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
expires: -1

Comment: Firefox is not a webkit browser, it uses Gecko. Can you post the ajax request details? If it keeps spinning probably it's because there is something wrong with the server that provides the api.

Comment: $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: url,
      data: params
     })
     .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
      amplify.publish('fail', error);
      self.stopSpin();
     })
     .done(function(data, status, xhr) {
      self.queryvalueChanged = false;
      amplify.publish('done', data);
      self.stopSpin();
     });    --- It works ion internet explorer, so i think server api might not be hvg any issues.

Comment: What happens when you visit directly the URL with a browser (firefox or chrome)? Does it complete the request?

Comment: It doesn't complete the request, i don't see anything in response, This is what i see in Timing tab -- **"Caution: Request is not finished yet"**

Comment: In this case I think that the problem lies in the server, somehow it doesn't finish the request correctly. Maybe it's using something not standard that IE understands but it's hard to tell without knowing how it's implemented.

Comment: This works when i use Fiddler and decrypt https request.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was server side, i was getting extra data in JSON response and data binding was not happening properly in chrome, firefox and safari.

Whereas IE is having loose binding policy i guess that's reason it was working in IE